# is it possible to use multiple proxies for different target websites?

Tags: proxy

Typically I'd like to know if it's possible to have a setup where it maps some IPs with a particular proxy and other IPs using another proxy?

`Proxy Chaining` isn't really what I'm looking for (*well I don't think it is*) because each address could be resolved with or without a proxy but **their content may not be accessible** without the right proxy.

This setup could be part of home network, so that the relevant proxy s/w could be installed and setup on a Linux box for ex.

**Ex**:

- website-A *via* proxy-1
- website-B *via* proxy-2
- all others *via*
  no-proxy

Comment: Just a pot shot here, as never really had a need for a proxy, but would something like foxyproxy addon for firefox, or rather software that is equivalent to that but for the whole computer and not just the browser be what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a solution.

You need to create a `proxy.pac` file that describes all such mappings. Actually it is a JavaScript file with a function that accepts 2 arguments (one is the URL and another one is hostname from this URL) and it should return the proxy server address or "DIRECT" for direct connections. The complete description of the proxy.pac is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config).

Some browsers allow to specify only `http://` URL to retrieve this file (e.g. InternetExplorer).
Some allow to use `file://` URL. Google Chrome has a command-line option `--proxy-pac-url`

Most of browsers may detect its location automatically (see `WPAD Standard` at the page referred above)

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution without using Pac files or Profiles too. Ghost Proxy Control lets you assign a different proxy to each TAB. (disclaimer: I'm the founder of Ghost Browser, the maker of this tool). There is a video demo of it here: [different proxy for each tab](https://ghostbrowser.com/blog/set-different-proxy-for-each-tab/).